# cv2 python frames can be shown, but not saved to file

Tags: python, opencv, video, python-imaging-library

i'm trying to record a video clip.
I have an object "observer" that created frames.

When i "imshow" images - i can see everything OK.
I have an "avi" file being generated. But when i try to view it - it is empty. clip is 0 seconds of black screen.

What am i missing?

```
frames_count = 0

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 15.0, frame_size)
while True:
    img_pil = observer.get()
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img_pil), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    writer.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow(f"frame (q: {observer.q.qsize()})", frame)
    frames_count += 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0Xff == ord('q'):
        break
    if frames_count > 30:
        break

writer.release()
```

Comment: `frame` is not of size `frame_size`, is it? remember, VideoWriter wants `(width, height)`, but numpy shapes are `(height, width, channels)` -- what does `assert writer.isOpened()` say?

Comment: I diffed the answer given below. it's a low-quality non-answer. the answer below merely adds two lines, line 2 and 3, that use `video.get`. it references a *nonexistent* `video` variable. the newly assigned `width` and `height` are never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the image is grayscale.
This line:

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 15.0, frame_size)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 15.0, frame_size,0)
```